# Оракл ограничение уникальности ошибка

Tags: oracle

Почему у меня ошибка, когда я делаю constraint unique на два столбца моей таблицы.

```
CREATE table my_table
(
Id number unique,
Numb_id number unique,
Name varchar2(50)
)
```

Почему оракл не дает мне создать два уникальных поля, но уникальные они должны быть не в паре, а сами по себе (пример таблицы рандомный, в моей задаче мне нужно именно так, просто таблица большая, так удобнее на маленькой показать).
Как можно такое переделать, чтобы оракл не ругался.

Comment: Какая именно ошибка появляется и в какой момент? В момент создания таблицы?

Comment: Нет таких ограничений в Оракле. [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/NhcUE6aq). Точный текст и запроса, и ошибки - в студию.

Comment: ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT UC_my_table UNIQUE (Id, Numb_id);